# How to autorun detect.py (Yolov5) when add video to folder?

Tags: python, yolov5

I already trained and got weight file in folder.
I'd like to know. How to autorun detect.py (python detect.py --weights runs/train/exp/weights/best.pt --img 640 --conf 0.3 --source data/images/AAA.avi --save-txt) automatic when I put my video in folder.

Please recommend to me Thank you so much.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, modify the main function so that detect.py can be executed in another Python file.

```
def main(opt):
    check_requirements(exclude=('tensorboard', 'thop'))
    run(**vars(opt))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    opt = parse_opt()
    main(opt)
```

Replace the above with the below.

```
def main(video):
    global video_path
    video_path = video
    opt = parse_opt()
    check_requirements(exclude=('tensorboard', 'thop'))
    run(**vars(opt))
```

And you need to modified on 78 line in detect.py

```
    source = str(source)
```

edit the source.

```
    source = video_path
```

weights, img, and conf, which are parsers excluding source, can be put in the default of the parse_opt function or directly in the run function. I modified the parser's default to avoid conflicts.

```
parser.add_argument('--weights', nargs='+', type=str, default='runs/train/exp/weights/best.pt', help='model path(s)')
parser.add_argument('--conf-thres', type=float, default=0.3, help='confidence threshold')
```

Below is a python file that runs detect.py

```
import os

count = 0
while True:
    video_input = os.listdir('./data/images')
    if len(video_input) > count:
        count += 1
        detect.main('./data/images' + video_input[-1])
```

Comment: would you mind to teach me ? I created python for auto run detect.py but when I ran python file, It doesn't have anything when I import my new video.

Comment: @Kukkik  you need to modified on 78 line in detect.py from ```save_img = not nosave and not source.endswith('.txt')``` to ```save_img = True```

Comment: I changed from your recommend but Error message is shown "detect.py.main('./data/images' + video_input[-1])
NameError: name 'detect' is not defined"

Comment: @Kukkik you have to define detect. Just add import detect in the python file to run detect.py.

Comment: Oh Thank you Now I can run detection. If I'd like to save text file too(--save txt) . how can I add to python file.

Comment: @Kukkik it's so simple. add under 78 line in detect.py ```save_txt = True```

Comment: I changed  'save_txt = True'  but I don't get label(text) files when run finished.

Comment: @Kukkik it's also simple. add under 78 line in detect.py save_crop = True

Comment: parser.add_argument('--save-txt',default="true", action='store_true', help='save results to *.txt')

Comment: @Desty when using images as input the execution is not stopping and keeps running. Any solutions?

Comment: @SindujanNirmalan I can't solve the problem without looking at your code because my code works fine.

Comment: I'd like to have more question. For last project I can Autorun with your recommend but when I move to other project. error as shown
"LOGGER.info(colorstr(s) + ', '.join(f'{k}={v}' for k, v in args.items()))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'"

Please suggest to me. How I can fix it. @Desty

Comment: @Kukkik Since LOGGER doesn't affect functionality, if you don't need to store any information, commenting it out solves the error.